Magento 2 : Customer Address Edit Form Country Default value set US in admin
In magento admin,customer address edit form country default value set US.

How achieve this?

Do you want to this only into admin?

yes @DhirenVasoya

In the admin got to

Store -> Configuration -> General -> General

In there you can set the Default Country.
